# in socket.io, when does the client.id change?

Tags: node.js, tcp, websocket, socket.io

if the server is connected to a websocket client using `socket.io`, what are the events that would cause the `client.id` to change?

1. the server reset
2. the client opening a new connection

are there others, such as timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When client connects to the socket.io server, then new `id` is generated for the connection. And there is no other place where `id` is generated.

Server reset, client opening new connection, timeout (and reconnection) - all of these trigger creation of new `id`, because actually client has to create a new connection to the socket.io server.

Comment: so timeout is tied to the `heartbeat` from the server, and if broken, attempt a new connection which would have a new client ID.  is this correct?